# iText7: Adding a PDF inside a Cell (cutoff at end of page)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

We are creating a PDF, it contains a large table, with headers (bold), sub-headers (non bold), rows and cells.
[image]

One of the requirements is to add an already existing PDF (can be multiple pages) inside the cell (under the sub-header). And this is where we are struggling. What we have tried so far:

Converting the PDF to a `FormXObject`, and adding that into the cell.

```
FontProvider fontProvider = new FontProvider();
ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();
props.SetFontProvider(fontProvider);

var historyId = text.Replace("=Spectec_template", "");

var pdfTemplate = templateToPdfClient.GetPdf(historyId, "HI").Result;
PdfDocument srcDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfTemplate.FileStream));
for (int i = 1; i < srcDoc.GetNumberOfPages() + 1; i++)
{
    Cell newCell = new Cell(1, columnInfo.ColumnSpan).SetFont(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(_fontName));
    PdfPage origPage = srcDoc.GetPage(i);

    Rectangle rect = origPage.GetPageSize();
    PdfFormXObject pageCopy = origPage.CopyAsFormXObject(pdf);
    Image image = new Image(pageCopy);
    image.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    image.SetMaxWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));
    image.SetMaxHeight(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(50));

    Div div = new Div();
    div.Add(image.SetMaxWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100)));

    newCell.Add(div);
    newCell = ApplyLayoutsToCell(newCell, cellStyles);
    table.AddCell(newCell);
}
```

But the end result is that we only see 1 page and it's completely overlapping at the end of the page.
[image]

When we set `image.SetAutoScale(true);` the PDF is visible but it's extremely small.
When adding the `Image` to a `Paragraph` instead of a DIV the PDF pages display next to each other.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: How exactly do you want the imported pages to be displayed? Shall they be arranged horizontally next to each other? Or vertically? Or in some grid? Shall they be scaled to fit? Or cut off?

Comment: The PDF we are creating is horizontal, and the PDF's we are adding are vertical. So I think our preferred way for them to be displayed would be: Vertically, scaled to fit (but preferably take up the whole page), and they can take up multiple pages (one page in the added PDF can be one page in the new PDF).

Comment: If you want each of the original pages to be on a separate page in the result, putting all of the page images into a single cell which is set to keep-together obviously is not what you want. Thus, I'd remove that keep-together setting and try putting each page into a separate cell.

Comment: Getting a lot closer indeed, thank you! I'm just struggling with the cutting off / overlapping at the bottom now. Any ideas there?

Comment: What happens if you use `image.SetAutoScale(true)` with these changes?

Comment: The images become minuscule, they try to fit on a page where there basically isn't any space left.

Comment: Hhmm, ok, I'm not really into this layout'ing stuff. I would probably try also setting some `setMinHeight` on the images, absolute or relative.

Comment: `image.setMinHeight(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(70))` etc did not seem to have any effect on the image itself. However `image.Scale(0.6f, 0.6f);` like @KJ suggested did seem to have a positive effect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @mkl and @KJ I figured this out.

I ended up adding each PDF page in a new Cell, and setting the scaling of image to 0.6f.

```
for (int i = 1; i < srcDoc.GetNumberOfPages() + 1; i++)
{
    newCell = new Cell(1, columnInfo.ColumnSpan).SetFont(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(_fontName));

    PdfPage origPage = srcDoc.GetPage(i);

    PdfFormXObject pageCopy = origPage.CopyAsFormXObject(pdf);
    Image image = new Image(pageCopy);
    image.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    image.Scale(0.6f, 0.6f);

    newCell.Add(image);
    newCell = ApplyLayoutsToCell(newCell, cellStyles);

    table.AddCell(newCell);
}
```